# How do you add a data connection to an existing table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an existing table in Excel (not a pivot table, just a regular table) that I've been updating by pasting in the contents of a similar table I download periodically from a reporting site. I now have the ability to access the same data directly from an Oracle database. How do I modify the existing table in Excel to pull data from the db? I know how to make the db connection itself. But there doesn't seem to be a way to add a connection to an existing table. I don't want to create a new connection and new table, and delete the old one, because it'll invalidate all the formulas throughout the workbook that refer to the existing table.

Comment: https://www.devart.com/odbc/oracle/docs/excel.htm

Comment: This isn't what I was asking - this is the part I said I knew.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Excel to add data source to existing table.

What you can do:

- create a new table with the connection
- replace old table name to new table name in formulas

Answer (score 0):

This comment from Reddit that someone pointed me to will get me there.
https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/m8tspw/_/grmjnnw